# Does Python's defaultdict violate the LSP?

Tags: python, solid, liskov-substitution

I believe, in Python `defaultdict` inherited from `dict` violates Liskov Substitution Principle. `defaultdict` doesn't raise `KeyError` while `x in d` is still `False`, for instance.

Is that so? If it is, why developer decided to make such a sacrifice?

Comment: Only the developer who "made the sacrifice" could tell you why.

Comment: It's a principle, not a <deleted> law.

Comment: I'm with @David Hammen.  Should we scrap Python cause it violates one of the more "fine print" aspects of the LSP?  Many language designers (see Java Collections) chose to violate strict LSP so *they could get work done*.

Comment: @user949300 There is an ocean of difference between scrapping Python and asking why a specific choice was made that seems to go against common wisdom.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**At first sight, yes**

At first sight it seems to violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle#Principle):

> If S is a subtype of T, then objects of type T in a program may be
>   replaced with objects of type S without altering any of the desirable
>   properties of that program

If you have a program written for a `dict` dictionary, that should look for words read in a stream, and do something if the words are not found (aka `KeyError` occurs), the same program would not work with a `defaultdict` because this would never cause a `KeyError` to happen (which is an expected invariant for `dict`).

Here we could open a debate, that only the Python designers could close:

- To be fully compliant with the LSP, they should have created an `abstract_dict` that defines the shared interface, but makes no claim on the behavior in case of a missing key.  Then they should have made dict, `defaultdict` and `ordereddict` inherit from `abstract_dict`. You would then use the three types of dictionnary in the same manner, but knowing that they are "sibbligns", you would not expect that they guarantee the same behavior.  But you already know that from the current documentation, don't you ?
- As the `abstract_dict` would not be very useful in the library, and as many of the methods certainly have the same implementation, the designers chose the inheritance. The idea is to reuse an implementation. Of course this kind of reuse violates the LSP.  I suppose they have carefully evaluated the risks.  But what's the risk for you if you knowingly choose `defaultdict`, because you prefer working with empty values instead of `KeyError` ?
- I suppose they have also compared the potential risks with the benefits: if in future, new features would be added to dict, this inheritance model would ensure that `defaultdict` would remain consistent at a lesser cost.

**But in looking in depth, defaultdict is fully LSP compliant**

First sights can mislead.  In fact semantically speaking a `defaultdict` **is-a** `dict`.  Parameters and return values are the same. Behavior is exactly the same for all programs that verify existence of the key (aka `key in d`) before trying to address it.

Even more, if you look closely at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict), for `dict`,  it is said:

> d[key]
>
> Return the item of d with key key. Raises a KeyError if key is not in the map.
>
> If a subclass of dict defines a method `__missing__()` and key is not present, the `d[key]` operation calls that method with the key key
>   as argument. The `d[key]` operation then returns or raises whatever is
>   returned or raised by the `__missing__(key)` call. No other operations
>   or methods invoke `__missing__()`. If `__missing__()` is not defined,
>   KeyError is raised. `__missing__()` must be a method; it cannot be an
>   instance variable:

This means that you can't assume `KeyError`  when you use dict: you have to assume that a different value could be returned or error raised. The claimed invariant is more complex, and it is defined in such a manner that it really covers the behavior of `defaultdict`.

By the way, `defaultdict` seems to have its properties by using the `__missing__()` method. And by the way, if no factory is provided in its constructor, it will raise a `KeyError` as `dict` would (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)).

So it seems to me that it's fully compliant.

Comment: Your reasoning is incorrect. First of all, `is-a` is not the be-all end-all criteria for determining subtyping. It is merely a rule of thumb. Secondly, it doesn't matter that the documentation mentions the `missing()` method; that is part of the implementation, not the interface. The interface to `d[key]` specifies that a `KeyError` is thrown when the key is not present. Documenting that that behavior may differ in a subclass does not change the fact that `defaultdict()` violates LSP, *it merely documents it*.

Comment: That entire paragraph is the documentation for d[key]. You don't get to stop reading at the first period just because they didn't phrase it as "does x unless y then does z"

Comment: @gardenhead, on what criteria is `__missing__` part of the implementation instead of the interface?

Comment: @WinstonEwert Well, Python doesn't have an interface in the formal sense because it lacks types. But what I meant is that `dict` throws a `KeyError` if the key is missing. That is the interface. The subclass does not throw a `KeyError` (or a subtype of `KeyError`) if the key is missing. Thus they have different interfaces.

Comment: @StarWeaver I didn't stop reading. I stated clearly that this behavior *is* documented. But documentation is not code, nor part of the interface.

Comment: You can also monkey-stuff a __missing__ onto an existing dict object of the base class and have it work as expected…

Comment: `__missing__` is clearly an example of the template method pattern.  As for abstract_dict, it's called `collections.abc.MutableMapping`.

Comment: @gardenhead the LSP is not about code but about specified predictable behavior (preconditions, postconditions, invariants), i.e. a black box approach. If you just look at the interface, you would only able to find out that the operator returns a value and might raise a KeyError. That's still the case with defaultdict. Where does the assumption that KeyError would be raised in absence of key come from? If from documentation, you have to take into account the full para an not only the first line. If from the code, you'd find out about the __missing__ as well. So, where is the problem ?

Comment: OK, I'm convinced. LSP is about _contract_, and _contract_ is not merely a bunch of methods.

Comment: You could still assume a `KeyError` will be raised if a queried element doesn't exist; `defaultdict` just makes sure that condition never exists in its world.

Comment: Well, I see this is a fruitless argument. There's no point arguing formal behavior in a language that doesn't even let you specify interfaces, abstractions, or types. Do what you will in the wild west of Python.

Comment: to rephrase what @Blrfl said: a default dict *always* contains the keys you ask it about.

Comment: Good lord. I had no idea you could practice language law in the context of Python until now.

Answer (score 6):

LSP does not mean a subclass should behave **exactly** like it's superclass in any piece of code that accepts the superclass(and therefore also the subclass). This would make polymorphism much less useful - after all, you subclass because you want to change the behavior. Rather, LSP means that a subclass may replace it's superclass without altering the desired properties of the code that accepts it. In other words, if someone wrote a code that accepts the superclass, it must also work as intended when receiving the subclass.

Now, pragmatism is more important than blindly following best practices. Here is a function that may work on `dict` but fail on `defaultdict` with the same values:

```
def foo(dct):
    try:
        _ = dct[12]
        assert 12 in dct
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

So in theory the LSP is broken, but pragmatically - who would write such code? Writing a function that works on the superclass but not on it's subclasses is **always** possible(`assert type(arg) == superclass`) but that's not the typical code that people write. With dictionaries, you would either:

- Access the member and if it doesn't exist, catch a `KeyError` and do some other thing. With `defaultdict`, you simply do the original thing with the default value.
- Check if the member is in the dict. In that case, `defaultdict` will behave like an ordinary dict.
- Use `.get` to pick your own default value. Actually, this one is broken in Python2(it'll use the `defaultdict`'s default instead of the one you specified), but in Python3 it again works like a regular `dict`.

You don't usually use these methods to validate each other - you pick the one that best fits your piece of code and use it. So if your code worked with `dict`, and you are not intentionally trying to break it for `defaultdict` - it should also work and do as intended with `defaultdict`.

Comment: “who would write such code” — People use `except KeyError` on a regular basis though it's not correct as @Christophe explained.

Comment: @Christophe referred to the docs that said a `dict` subclass may override `__missing__` to change the behavior when the key you look for is not in the dictionary. This means that using `except KeyError:` to **check** whether or not the dictionary contains the item is incorrect, since a subclass(like `defaultdict`) may decide to change that behavior. However, people don't(at least they shouldn't) use `expect KeyError:` for this purpose - if they want to check the existence they have the `in` operator.

Comment: When people use `KeyError` it's not to **check** for the existence, but to **specify** the behavior when the key is missing. "Get the value for that key and do X with it, but if that key is not in the dictionary do Y instead". `defaultdict` should not break that code. True, it won't do Y, but it will return a default value that will be used when doing X.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw `except KeyError` where `x in d` should be for dozens of times.

Comment: There should be a limit to how much effort one has to make to be compatible with crappy code...

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it violates LSP. This is one reason why inheritance (and nominal sub-typing in general) is dangerous: developers usually get it wrong. As for why it was made this way: you'd have to ask the developers.

Comment: Downvoter care to share?